# How to create a znode asynchronously in Apache Curator

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

With the fluent API of Curator, we can create a znode synchronously by invoking something like:

```
client.create().withMode(CreateMode.PERSISTENT).forPath("/mypath", new byte[0]);
```

I would like to know how we can execute the same operation asynchronously while specifying the create mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can execute the given create operation asynchronously while specifying the create mode like below,

```
    client.create()
          .withMode(CreateMode.PERSISTENT)
          .inBackground()
          .forPath("/mypath", new byte[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Java 8 and ZooKeeper 3.5.x, the latest version of Curator (note: I'm the main author) has a new DSL for async. You can read about it here: http://curator.apache.org/curator-x-async/index.html

E.g.

```
AsyncCuratorFramework async = AsyncCuratorFramework.wrap(client);
async.checkExists().forPath(somePath).thenAccept(stat -> mySuccessOperation(stat));
```

Comment: In my case, I was using Zookeeper 3.4.10. And curator 2.9.X